# Action Method That Looks Up Search Results via a Class, Passes Them to View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a `Results` action method to the `SearchController` class in this file: [SearchController.cs](https://github.com/user3546086/TechJobsMVC/blob/master/src/TechJobs/Controllers/SearchController.cs).

- The method should take in two parameters, specifying the type of search and the search term (I already did this - the field names were found in [Index.cshtml](https://github.com/user3546086/TechJobsMVC/blob/master/src/TechJobs/Views/Search/Index.cshtml)). After looking up the search results via the `JobData` class, I need to pass them into the [Index.cshtml](https://github.com/user3546086/TechJobsMVC/blob/master/src/TechJobs/Views/Search/Index.cshtml) View. *This is not the default view for this aciton*.
- I also need to pass `ListController.columnChoices` to the view, as is done in the `Index` method in [SearchController.cs](https://github.com/user3546086/TechJobsMVC/blob/master/src/TechJobs/Controllers/SearchController.cs).

First of all, I don't know if I'm looking up the search results via the JobData class correctly (The JobData class can be found in [JobData.cs](https://github.com/user3546086/TechJobsMVC/blob/master/src/TechJobs/Models/JobData.cs)).

In the SearchController file, you can see that I tried this:

```
public IActionResult Results (string searchType, string searchTerm)
{
    //look up search results via JobData class   
    JobData.FindByValue(searchTerm);

    //pass them into Views/Search/index.cshtml 

    //pass ListConroller.columnChoices to view, as is done in the Index method
    ViewBag.columns = ListController.columnChoices;
    ViewBag.title = "Search";
    return View();
}
```

I don't know if passing searchTerm to `JobData.FindByValue` is going to look up the search results. If not searchTerm, what should I pass to `JobData.FindByValue`?

Second, I don't know how to pass the search results to the Index.cshtml View. I don't see a View method anywhere in that file - I don't know where the search result information goes and what formatting a pass would look like.

Right now when I run this project, I'm actually getting an error message for Index.cshtml:

[image]

I haven't touched this file and it wasn't giving me an error message before - why now?

Also, [here](http://techjobs20170314011743.azurewebsites.net/) is a demo of this project working properly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try to put "@title" instead of "@.title"?

Comment: If you want a custom search action where users can specify the criteria to filter the results, then you should use ODATA for it.

Comment: @StfBln I tried it and am still getting the error message: http://i.imgur.com/U2e9bRM.png

Comment: @HappyHands31 now it complains about something else. Since the "." has been removed, it complains it cannot find "title". Seeing your code, replacing "@title" by "@ViewBag.title" will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
public IActionResult Results (string searchType, string searchTerm)
{
    //look up search results via JobData class   
    //if user searches 'all'
    if (searchType == "all")
    {
        ViewBag.Jobs = JobData.FindByValue(searchTerm);
    }
    //if user searches by category
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Jobs = JobData.FindByColumnAndValue(searchType, searchTerm);
    }
    //pass them into Views/Search/index.cshtml 
    return View("~/Views/SearchController/Index.cshtml");
}
```

I was on the right track with `JobData.FindByValue(searchTerm)` but I wasn't assigning it to anything - I needed to assign it to the `ViewBag.Jobs` object. Then I needed to create an If - Else Statement where if the user selects "all", I'd use the FindByValue method, and if the user selects anything else, I'd use the FindByColumnAndValue method, which receives two arguments.

To pass the results into Views/Search/index.cshtml, you literally specify the path:

```
return View("~/Views/SearchController/Index.cshtml");
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears like the engine cannot parse your view due to a period right after "@". It appears as well that you assign your title to the viewbag using `ViewBag.title = "Search";`.

In order to correct the view error, you can change the following:

```
<h1>@.title</h1>
```

to

```
<h1>@ViewBag.title</h1>
```

And you should be not have this error anymore.

Comment: This does fix that problem. How did you know how to do `@viewBag.title`?  But still, I'm not sure about whether or not I'm looking up search results via the JobData class correctly....or if I'm passing the search results into Views?

Comment: @HappyHands31 I have edited the reply to provide a bit more information on why the view had to be changed that way.